# OWASP ZAP baseline scan returns unexpected error 1 in CI/CD pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, pipeline, owasp, zap

I am using a docker image from OWASP in my pipeline to scan my web app and produce a HTML report, and I am encountering a problem I've spent the whole day trying to solve.

When running the scan job, it will successfully scan the website, but immediatly after executing the scan command, the job will stop and return "error: job failed: exit code 1".

This happens without precisions on what has failed in the command.

Here is the code of my job :

```
zap_scan:
  stage: owasp
  image:
    name: owasp/zap2docker-stable
  script:
    - mkdir /zap/wrk
    - /zap/zap-baseline.py -t http://webURL.com -g gen.conf -r /zap/wrk/report.html
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - /zap/wrk/report.html
```

Normally, this shouldn't be returning an error as a I have tested the scan command by running this on a locally built, identic docker image and I have encountered no issues (ie the scan and the file were generated properly).

[Here is the open source code of the zap-baseline.py script](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/blob/main/docker/zap-baseline.py)

By looking into this, I've found that the script can return error 1 if fail_count is different than 0.

I do not understand why the script behave differently on a local docker image and in a pipeline, can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gitlab sends an automatic error when a script returns 1, which was the case because the scan had warnings. Adding the option -I fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to share the full output from the scan (obfuscating anything sensitive) in order for us to be able to help more.

btw, why are you specifying `-g gen.conf` ? That generates a config file, which you do not appear to be using..

Comment: Due to company policy I cannot share the full output from the scan, however I can assure you that the scan from the local docker image is fully clean without problems.

I think this issue is related to the pipeline files manipulation, as if I add another command after the scan in my pipeline, the command will be not executed and the job will terminate immediatly after the scan.

The conf file is the default one, it was probably unnecessary to use it, but it's not the source of the error as it is reproduced without the option config file.

Comment: So it sounds like its not a ZAP problem?

Comment: It wasn't actually a ZAP problem. Gitlab sends an automatic error when a script returns 1, which was the case because the scan had warnings.
Adding the option -I fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working gitlab job for zap scan.

```
zap-scan:
  stage: owasp
  image:
    name: owasp/zap2docker-stable:latest
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p /zap/wrk
  script:
    - echo "Starting zap-api-scan.py baseline scan"
    - cp ./owasp-zap/warn-levels.config /zap/wrk
    - zap-api-scan.py -t http://webURL.com -c warn-levels.config -w testreport.md -r testreport.html -S -I
    - cp /zap/wrk/testreport.md testreport.md
    - cp /zap/wrk/testreport.html testreport.html
    - grep -Po '\| High \| 0 \|' testreport.md
    - grep -Po '\| Medium \| 0 \|' testreport.md
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - zap.out
      - testreport.md
      - testreport.html
```

Note the flag `-c with warn-levels.config` this extra config you can provide to configure the errors which you want to ignore.

In our case, we wanted to exclude

```
WARN-NEW: Spring Actuator Information Leak [40042] x 1
```

So, the file `warn-levels.config` looks like below

```
40042   IGNORE  (Spring Actuator Information Leak - Active/release)
```

Reference for the various flags https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/api-scan/#usage